# How do I change background for webslides

Tags: html, css

I do not know how to change the background in Webslides. This is what I have tried:

```html
<section class="bg-gradient-r aligncenter">
      <span class="background" style="background-color: dodgerblue"></span>
      <h1>Depression: What You Need To Know</h1>
</section>
```

The background changed, but the heading disappeared after one second. That is not what I want. How do I change the background color while keeping the heading on the page?

Comment: Hi @ComputerCoder, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, I can't effectively help you without a demo of the problem. Could you give me a link to your website or make a JSfiddle, CodePen, or Stackoverflow Snippet clearly showing your problem?

Comment: The snippet does not reproduce the problem. Is h1 not suppose to be included or parented by the span tag, which normally should be CSSed as a block if it is to operate as a block? As an inline span with no content it has no content to add a background to. If you are making changes to the CSS with javascript that would need to be posted. If you are making changed via CSS only (IE :checked  with label tag) that would need to be posted.